# Why doesn't an HTML slider pick up ng-attr-max?

Tags: angularjs

Consider this simple example (available as a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/7omvjxas/)):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <form>
        <input 
            type="range" 
            ng-model="mainCtrl.range.value" 
            ng-attr-min="mainCtrl.range.min" 
            ng-attr-max="mainCtrl.range.max" />
    </form>
    <div>{{mainCtrl.range.min}} -- {{mainCtrl.range.value}} -- {{mainCtrl.range.max}}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('AngularTestApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [function () {
    var self = this;
    self.range = {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        value: 3
    };
}]);
```

Sliding the slider all the way to the right produces a value of 100, much more than the maximum of 10 that the slider should be set to. Why? How do I programmatically set the maximum value of an HTML slider through an AngularJS binding?

(N.B. There is an open AngularJS bug [ng-model does not set initial value and position of input[type=range] #6726](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726) but that is about setting the initial value of the slider, which works fine in my code.)

Comment: You forget the braces: `ng-attr-min="{{mainCtrl.range.min}}" `, and so on.

Comment: Missing braces {{}} http://jsfiddle.net/ph88kx77/

Comment: Not sure why this is down-voted? But in any case, if either of you can add your comments as an answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks for the answer, I'm definitely confused about when I need and do not need those braces (e.g. I do not need them for ng-model="mainCtrl.range.value".)

Comment: You need them when the attribute expects a plain value, not a variable to work with, but this value is stored in a variable. Anyway, it's always clearly indicated in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Blackhole. What's the rule of thumb for which attributes expect a plain value and which can work with an expression? Or is it just a case of looking each one up?

Comment: When you don't expect the attribute to be able to work in both way (it will make no sense for it to modify a variable), it usually expects a value. One exception is the attributes that are useless if used without a variable (for instance, `ngClass`, which should be replaced with the classical `class` if used without variable) ; it avoid the use of heavy braces in such cases. But **always look at the documentation** to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments on the question from [Blackhole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057033/blackhole) and [sqiroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632286/squiroid) but I'll pull them out here too so that the question does not sit unanswered.

It was a simple case of me missing out the double curly brackets. The code should read:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <form>
        <input 
            type="range" 
            ng-model="mainCtrl.range.value" 
            ng-attr-min="{{mainCtrl.range.min}}" 
            ng-attr-max="{{mainCtrl.range.max}}" />
    </form>
    <div>{{mainCtrl.range.min}} -- {{mainCtrl.range.value}} -- {{mainCtrl.range.max}}</div>
</div>
```

And sqiroid provides a revised JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ph88kx77/).

I find it difficult to judge when to use double curly brackets or not; in my original code it was not obvious to me that `ng-model` had different requirements to both `ng-attr-min` and `ng-attr-max`. In further comments on the original question Blackhole gives some useful rules-of-thumb for judging when one might need double curly brackets (or not):

1. If the HTML attribute's value cannot set the AngluarJS model's value, then the attribute usually expects a value and not an expression and so one should expect to use double curly brackets.
2. If the attribute is useless if used without a variable (for instance, ngClass) then provide an expression not a value, i.e. do not use double curly brackets.

But Blackhole goes on to stress that one should "always look at the documentation to be sure".